# aiobotocore / aiohttp DNS Hangs

Tags: python, async-await, aiohttp

I'm using aiobotocore and encountering what might potentially be a DNS issue. I use a few different AWS services (SQS, S3, KMS) but so far it only occurs with SQS, which is used heavily. I haven't been able to reproduce it locally and it can take hours to occur in AWS. The code is currently deployed to AWS ECS Fargate.

This line hangs and times out: https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/blob/master/aiohttp/connector.py#L1093

The container image is deployed and run as an API server and as a background worker. Both the API server and background worker run this library and interact with SQS, but only the background worker is having this issue. I thought perhaps it was a connection pooling issue since the worker would use more connections, but only one async task long polls receive_message and the error is occurring while resolving DNS, which is during connection creation.

I added a timeout and used the backoff library around the SQS calls to timeout and back them off, which seems to be helping, but it keeps occurring.

pip versions:

```
aiobotocore==2.1.0
aiodns==3.0.0
aiohttp==3.8.1
aiosignal==1.2.0
async-timeout==4.0.2
botocore==1.23.24
```

python 3.9.7

```
    await self.__sqs_client.change_message_visibility(
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiobotocore/client.py", line 173, in _make_api_call
        http, parsed_response = await self._make_request(
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiobotocore/client.py", line 193, in _make_request
        return await self._endpoint.make_request(operation_model, request_dict)
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiobotocore/endpoint.py", line 93, in _send_request
        success_response, exception = await self._get_response(
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiobotocore/endpoint.py", line 111, in _get_response
        success_response, exception = await self._do_get_response(
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiobotocore/endpoint.py", line 147, in _do_get_response
        http_response = await self._send(request)
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiobotocore/endpoint.py", line 229, in _send
        return await self.http_session.send(request)
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiobotocore/httpsession.py", line 172, in send
        resp = await self._session.request(
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 535, in _request
        conn = await self._connector.connect(
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 542, in connect
        proto = await self._create_connection(req, traces, timeout)
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 907, in _create_connection
        _, proto = await self._create_direct_connection(req, traces, timeout)
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 1154, in _create_direct_connection
        hosts = await asyncio.shield(host_resolved)
        asyncio.exceptions.CancelledError
```

The CancelledError is coming from being timed out in the function above this call, but the aiohttp host resolve line is where it hangs.

Comment: FWIW I've ran into what appears to be this issue too, twice recently, but in highly concurrent situations.  It's a bit early to be sure but the area in the code is identical and the symptoms largely too.  Unfortunately I don't have any answers for you either.